# Variable is changing without the program running

Tags: javascript, variables

On the website I am writing, there is an object called person which holds a variable called balance.  At one point I call the set method and change balance's value to 100 from 0.
I noticed there was a problem when the at the end running my program the value of balance was back to 0.  Placing a break point where it changes balance with the code

```
User.person.balance = Date.Parse(txtBal_Updated.Text)
```

it goes through the setter and changes the value from 0 to 100.  I stop the program right after this change and use the tracer to look at the value of balance and it say 100.  But if I look at person and through person to balance it shows that it is 0.  Then when I look back at balance it has suddenly changed back to 0 without me stepping through the program at all.  I am very confused how an objects value can change without the program running.

Comment: In what programming language are you writing? Please tell more about it

Comment: I'd also like a copy of the floppy in which the compiler for this language came. Pretty please!

Comment: "But if I look at person and through person to balance it shows that it is 0": how do you do that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

What is the thing that you call “your program” ? Is it some JavaScript in a Web page ? How do you run it ?

What is “the tracer” ? With what tool(s) you inspect the variables ?

Your problem makes me think strongly of **variable scope**. You may experience some **garbage-collecting** too.

You focus on **the variables** themselves. In your situation, I suspect first **the instrumentation**.

Comment: The program is written with visual basic (Not my choice) while I use microsoft visual studios.  It is run and traced through visual studios as well.

Comment: @Thomas — So your program runs as an executable application, it is not a sort of script. I see a problem in this : “I stop the program right after this change and use the tracer to look at the value of balance”. I don't trust any value you might see for a variable **after the program has stopped**. I would not even try to see a variable at this point. You are encountering a border of variable scope. **When a program stops running, all his variables vanish in smoke.**

Comment: @Thomas — Thomas, you are very confused how an object's value can change without the program running. As for me, call me a non-believer, I don't believe in an object's value **existing** without the program running. [ Variables, after they die, don't live in the Paradise of variables. For variables, the laws of life are not christian, they are more like reincarnation. :-) ] If you need to keep a value after the program has stopped, what you need is called **persistence**. For example, you can have persistence with **a file** (simple), or with **a database** (heavy).

Comment: sorry, I was a bit unclear, the program hasn't stopped, it hit a break point.  I am not sure but I thought that a variable would still exist during a break point and keep the value it last had until the programmer tells the program to continue.

Comment: @Thomas — A breakpoint is different. Are you sure that your program does not stop ? Are you sure that your program does not crash ?

Comment: It doesn't stop, and it doesn't crash.